# Convolutional NN pretrained on imagenet dataset (inceptionv3) raised an ValueError in ternsorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I tried to make Convolutional NN needs to be pretrained on imagenet dataset; TO do so, I used `inceptionv3` as base model that needs to be on the top of Convolutional NN, but it raised value error as follow:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b52791a606ee> in <module>()
      6 x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
      7 x = Flatten()(x)
----> 8 x = Dense(2048)(x)
      9 x = BatchNormalization()(x)
     10 x = Activation('relu')(x)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
   1166     last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])
   1167     if last_dim is None:
-> 1168       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
   1169                        'should be defined. Found `None`.')
   1170     self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: last_dim})

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

from error message, I can infer that the dimension of the inputs to dense are missing. I am not sure how to fix this up? Can anyone point me out what would be a quick debug solution for this? Any possible thoughts?

**my attempt**

here is current my attempt

```
from tensorflow.keras import  models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.input
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=x.shape[1:])(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(2048)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
outputs = x
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=outputs, name="cifar10_model")
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I want to use this on cifar10 multi-class image classification. My goal is I want convolutional NN needs to be pre-trained on `imagenet dataset` for the sake of weight initialization. I am not sure how to achieve this correctly. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen in TensorFlow? Any possible thoughts?

**extented thoughts**

if we can make above attempt as error-free, can we add a residual connection to the above attempt? Any way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a few problems with your code. First, you are connecting layers to the **input** of the Inception model whereas you want to be connecting layers to the output of the network. The first thing you need to do is change

```
x = base_model.input
```

to

```
x = base_model.output
```

Next, by printing out the output of each layer, we see that the shape you are feeding into each subsequent layer after the base model is `(None, None, None, 3)`. This is because you haven't defined an input shape for your model. To fix this, simply add the `input_shape` argument to your constructor.

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=shape)
```

Finally, when you construct your new model, the inputs to your model should be the inputs to the Inception network. So you need to change

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=outputs, name="cifar10_model")
```

to

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=outputs, name="cifar10_model")
```

Finally, to add a residual connection, you can either define a custom layer, or do some renaming such that you can access the identity layer into an `Add()` layer.

**FULLY WORKING**

```
def block(x, filters, stride=1):
    identity = x
    identity = Conv2D(4 * filters, 1, strides=stride, padding='same')(identity)
    identity = BatchNormalization()(identity)

    x = Conv2D(4 * filters, (3, 3), strides=stride, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Add()([identity, x])
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    return x


base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = block(base_model.output, 32, 1)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(2048)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
outputs = x
model = models.Model(base_model.input, outputs)
```

Comment: `input_shape` should take the shape of your data. For your dataset, `cifar`, I think the images are of size (32, 32, 3). So it would be `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)`.

Comment: I tried but I got ValueError again: `ValueError: Input size must be at least 75x75; got `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)``. How can we get out of this? Could you provide an error-free answer if it is possible? Thanks!

Comment: As for a residual connection, you can refer to the tensorflow github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/resnet.py#L229). This should take you to `block1()` which can guide you to how to implement the residual connection.

Comment: After taking a look at it, it seems that `(32, 32, 3)` is too small for InceptionV3. That's why you are getting a ValueError. To fix this, you will need to resize your images to atleast 75 by 75.

Comment: If you fully implement the changes I described, everything should work out in your model.

Comment: If you resized your images to be 99 by 99, make sure to change the input shape to be `(99, 99, 3)`.

Comment: I did resize image as `cv2.resize(x, (99,99,3))` but the error didn't go away. Can you show your coding solution in your gist or update your answer so I could reproduce it here? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my code in my answer. It seems that because you have a maxpooling layer with a stride of `(2, 2)`. There will be some for shape issues. To be safe, I changed the input dimension to be `(224, 224, 3)`. So, you will need to resize your images accordingly.

Comment: I am still not sure about resize image? Where exactly should I do resize input image? let's say we use cifar10, svhn and so on; can you indicate that in your fully working example? Also why the resulted model has a massive number of parameters? Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219719/discussion-between-richard-x-and-kim).

Answer (score 0):

The pretrained model takes the input shape, not the first Conv2D.
Try this:

```py
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape=x.shape[1:])
x = base_model.input
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(x)
...
```

EDIT: if you want residual connection, maybe you have to implement the layer on your own.

Comment: it is not working. I am getting this error: `ValueError: `input_shape` must be a tuple of three integers.`. Any possible update?